# How to get list of child class of a parent class?

Tags: c#, class

Is it possible to get a list of class name of `Parent` and list of the field names in class `ChildA`:

I created this class to define the configuration codes (because I don't want to use string, it is not stable and difficult to manage):

```
public class CodeConfiguration
    {
        public class ModuleA
        {
            public const string GroupA = "ProvinCode";
            public const string GroupB = "CountryCode";
        }
        public class ModuleB
        {
            public const string GroupC = "ImportStatus;
            public const string GroupD = "ExecuteStatus";
        }
    }
```

In database, my data table is as below

```
Module  Group   Code    Name
ModuleA GroupA  1       100
ModuleA GroupB  2       1001
ModuleB GroupC  1       Imported
ModuleB GroupD  2       Failed
```

So now I need to get data for `Module` Combobox and `Group` Combobox
My expected result:

Module Combobox: `{"ModuleA","ModuleB}`
Group Combobox of Module A: `{"GroupA","GroupB"}`

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: But you should not want this. For one thing, public nested classes are discouraged.

Comment: Note that you asked "list of the *variable names* in class ChildA" but did not show any... Are you sure you've used proper term for what you are looking for?

Comment: I have updated my question to show my expected result.

Comment: Those are not called variables, those are called fields,

Comment: I will slightly add to Henk's argument: Public nested classes are ***strongly*** discouraged. --- There are no good reasons or use-cases for doing it, as far as my experience goes; and most, if not all, of the developers I know seem to agree. --- @ScottChamberlain It's not *technically* accurate, I agree; but in real-world practice, most people use `variable` and `field` synonymously and even interchangeably (?). [insert shrug here]

Comment: @HoangTran That questions looks to me as if it's not the actual question you should ask. I say that because your goal is most likely not to do what you're asking, but you're trying to do what your asking in order to achieve something else.

Comment: @Tipx: I have updated my question to make it more cleary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of nested class names with:

```
var nestedClasses = typeof(CodeConfiguration)
    .GetNestedTypes()
    .Select(_ => _.Name)
    .ToList();
```

If you want to include private nested classes, pass `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic` as an argument to `.GetNestedTypes()` method.

Get list of field names with:

```
var fieldNames = typeof(CodeConfiguration.ModuleA)
    .GetFields()
    .Select(_ => _.Name)
    .ToList();
```

To include private fields, pass `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` as an argument to `.GetFields()` method.

---

See also [Reflection in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection)

Comment: Thank bro, I have updated the class names in my question so I updated them in your answer also

Comment: Hi bro, instead of typeof(CodeConfiguration.ModuleA), Is it possible to use a string name like typeof("ModuleA") ?

Comment: `typeof` doesn't support string as an argument, but you can use `Type.GetType(name)` or `Assembly.GetType(name)` instead.

Comment: I tried Type.GetType("MyNamespace.CodeConfiguration.ModuleA") but it was null.

Comment: unlike `Assembly,GetType()`, argument of `Type.GetType()` must be Assembly qualified name - see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.7#System_Type_GetType_System_String_)